# Algorithm to group overlapping objects

Tags: graphics, vector-graphics

Lets say I have a set of 100,000 rectangles of various sizes and oritentation. I want to group all overlapping rectangles to multiple groups.

**My current method** - group the rectangles into a Quadtree. Then for each and every rectangle compare against items within the item's leaf, parent and child to find overlapping rectangles. Then assign the rectangle a group ID if overlapping.

**I am looking for**  an algorithm faster than the semi-brute-force method above.

Thanks for your time!

Gary

Comment: Did you have a look at sweep and prune (http://jitter-physics.com/wordpress/?tag=sweep-and-prune) ?

Comment: You might also be interested by this answer on gamedev : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/87629/66389

Comment: Sweep and Prune does appear to be smarter way of acheiving my objective.  Thanks Zouch for the guidance.